# SPSS: warning in loop command

Tags: loops, spss

I have artificially manipulated the following data to understand the loop command in `SPSS`.

```
 JYEAR   POSITION
 89      
 89       2
 89       1
          2
          1
 99       1     
 99       
 99       2
```

THE BLANK SPACE DENOTE `MISSING VALUE`.

I WROTE DOWN THE SYNTAX:

```
 DO IF (JYEAR GT 90).
 COMPUTE BONUS=0.
 ELSE IF (POSITION EQ 1).
 COMPUTE  BONUS=.75.
 END IF.
 EXECUTE.
```

I SUPPOSED I WOULD GET THE FOLLOWING RESULT:

```
 JYEAR   POSITION   BONUS
 89                 
 89       2
 89       1          .75
          2          
          1          .75
 99       1           0
 99                   0
 99       2           0
```

BUT I GOT THE FOLLOWING `WARNING`:

```
 Warning # 142.  Command name: EXECUTE 
 LOOP has no effect on this command. 
 Error # 4095.  Command name: EXECUTE 
 The transformations program contains an unclosed LOOP, DO IF, or complex file 
 structure.  Use the level-of-control shown to the left of the SPSS Statistics 
 commands to determine the range of LOOPs and DO IFs. 
 Execution of this command stops.
```

Comment: The shown code is not syntactically wrong, so the error message comes from somewhere else. FYI the 5th row in the listed code would not evaluate to `.75`. One of the victims of SPSS's evaluation of missing data.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code would not produce that error message.  Do you have an outer loop containing this code that is not shown?

Note also that the EXECUTE command is superfluous.  It will just cause an unnecessary extra data pass.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this happens, but it is not due to an outer loop problem, as I have had it happen for me as well, and in my case, there is no outer loop. This is the entirety of the shared code. So SPSS is capable of doing this.

Simply leaving off the EXECUTE command resulted in the proper outcome for me, with pending transformations that simply had to be run. Not at all clear why EXECUTE would cause a problem like this, and haven't been able to find any reason for it.

Comment: As this is not an answer, you should probably make it a comment.

Comment: Commenting requires 50 reputation. In defense of this as an answer, I did point out that simply leaving off "execute" made it work for me, although I did have to manually run pending transformations